# React Typescript: Add another row of fields to form with button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, forms, react-native

I'm building a product sales form that allows users to add a `product name`, `quantity`, and `price`. By default I want the form to show 3 rows and if they want to add another product, there would be a button that says "Add Product" which will then add another two of `product name`, `quantity`, and `price`.

I want to set the limit to allow to a max of 10 rows (10 products).

```
addProductRow(event) { 
    event.preventDefault();
}

<div className={`${styles.flexWrap} ${styles.flexRow}`}>
    <div>
        <label>
            Product Name
        </label>
        <input
            value={this.state.DetailedDescription1}
            onChange={this.handleChangeDetailedDescription1}
            type="text"
            className="phone validate"
            name="Detailed Description"
            maxLength={45}
        />
    </div>  
    <div>
        <label>
            Quanitity
        </label>
        <input
            value={this.state.Quantity1}
            onChange={this.handleChangeQuantity1}
            type="number"
            className="phone validate"
            name="Quantity #1"
            maxLength={9}
            pattern='[0-9]{0,5}'
        />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>
            Total
        </label>
        <input
            value={this.state.Total1}
            onChange={this.handleChangeTotal1}
            type="number"
            className="phone validate"
            name="Quantity #1"
            maxLength={9}
            pattern='[0-9]{0,5}'
        />
    </div>
</div>

<button onClick={this.addProductRow}>Add New Product</button>
<button onClick={this.removeProductRow}>X</button>
```

So when the user clicks "Add New Product" a new row will show with the above fields labeled `this.state.DetailedDescription2` and `this.handleChangeDetailedDescription1` and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

you could store the row data in component state (below example uses the `useState` hook, but there are other approaches depending on your component structure):

```
const [rows, setRows] = useState([{ /* row1 data */ }, { /* row 2 data */ }, { /* row3 data */ }])
```

and then your `addProductRow` could look something like:

```
addProductRow(){
  if (this.state.rows.length > 9) return 'you cannot add more than 10 rows'
  const rows = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.rows)) // make a deep copy since this.state.rows is an array of objects
  rows.push({ /* "new row" data in here */ })
  setRows(rows)
}
```

then render the rows by doing

```
this.state.rows.map((row, i) => (/* ...all your jsx for a single row goes in here. you can use the index i to reference a specific row of this.state.rows in your change handlers. */))
```

Comment: let me try this, I'll get back to you shortly. When you say "row data" is that referring to the `this.state.Quantity1` ?

Comment: basically any data that is dynamic and specific to the current row should go inside that object

Comment: so a single row object might look like `{ detailedDescription: 'foo', quantity: 0, price: 10 }`

Comment: I'm doing something like this `const [rows, setRows] = useState([{ DetailedDescription1: '' , Quantity1: null, UnitPrice1: null}` and the `=` is giving me an `; expected` error and every comma in the useState is giving me an `: expected` error

Comment: how are you importing `useState` ?

Comment: `this.state = {DetailedDescription1: '' " , Quantity1: null, UnitPrice1: null}`

Comment: it would be helpful if you posted the whole file